# What's the song when Yato & Hiyori are hugging under the rocks when battling Rabo?

Tags: music, noragami

What's the OST from *Noragami* episode 12 around 14:36 when Yato & Hiyori are hugging under the rocks when battling Rabo?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the one you're looking for is this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2UKQ85d328).

It's called **"Wild Speech"**. You can check it out here -> [track 3](http://noragami.wikia.com/wiki/Noragami_Original_Soundtrack).

Comment: it's different, around 14:36 there's no rap only violin

Comment: or like in episode 9 around 20:00, do you know the background music?

Answer (score 0):

This track is "M14" (disc 2, track 13) from [the second version of the *Noragami Aragoto* soundtrack](http://vgmdb.net/album/56225). Here is [a 15-second extract](https://clyp.it/25pnjqmt?token=17c202ed0a82d9dcba2542b2cbdf7e17) from the beginning of the piece.